# AngularJS: View not displaying

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I started learning AngularJS one week ago and I'm trying to make something very simple without success. I can't find the mistake.  Currently, ui-view is not displaying any data. But checking with the borwser inspector anything seems to be wrong.  Help please and Thanks.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html ng-app="confusionApp" lang="en"><head>


    <body>

    <div class="container">
    <div class="row row-content" ng-controller="dishDetailController">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
             <div class="media">
                  <h2 class="media-heading">{{dish.name}}</h2>


            <p>Put the comments here</p>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>

<script src="../bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>

<script>

    var app = angular.module('confusionApp',[]);

    app.controller('dishDetailController', function() {

        var dish={
                      name:'Uthapizza',
                      image: 'images/uthapizza.png',
                      category: 'mains', 
                      label:'Hot',
                      price:'4.99',
                      description:'A unique combination of Indian Uthappam (pancake) and Italian pizza, topped with Cerignola olives, ripe vine cherry tomatoes, Vidalia onion, Guntur chillies and Buffalo Paneer.',
                       comments: []
                };

        this.dish = dish;

    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `this` in controller the you have to use `as` in controller name like this

```
ng-controller="dishDetailController as ctrl"
```

And access with controller instance like this

```
<h2 class="media-heading">{{ctrl.dish.name}}</h2>
```

If you don't wanna to use `as` in controller then attach your data with `$scope`

First inject `$scope`

```
app.controller('dishDetailController', function($scope) {
```

Then attach with `$scope`

```
$scope.dish = dish;
```

Comment: I have been trying to solve this for a few days. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

change your html like this

```
    <div class="row row-content" ng-controller="dishDetailController as dishDetail">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
         <div class="media">
              <h2 class="media-heading">{{dishDetail.dish.name}}</h2>
```

and see if it works ,

checkout Controller As syntax in angular [link](http://www.johnpapa.net/angularjss-controller-as-and-the-vm-variable/)

in order to use `this`  you must need controller as declaration

Answer (score 0):

Update controller to use scope, running example https://jsbin.com/dodaduwowe/edit?html,output

```
app.controller('dishDetailController', function($scope) {

        var dish={
                      name:'Uthapizza',
                      image: 'images/uthapizza.png',
                      category: 'mains', 
                      label:'Hot',
                      price:'4.99',
                      description:'A unique combination of Indian Uthappam (pancake) and Italian pizza, topped with Cerignola olives, ripe vine cherry tomatoes, Vidalia onion, Guntur chillies and Buffalo Paneer.',
                       comments: []
                };

        $scope.dish = dish;

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html ng-app="confusionApp" lang="en"><head>
    <body>

    <div class="container">
    <div class="row row-content" ng-controller="dishDetailController">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
             <div class="media">
                  <h2 class="media-heading">{{dish.name}}</h2>
            <p>Put the comments here</p>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
<script src="../bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>

<script>

    var app = angular.module('confusionApp',[]);

    app.controller('dishDetailController', function($scope) {

        $scope.dish={
                      name:'Uthapizza',
                      image: 'images/uthapizza.png',
                      category: 'mains', 
                      label:'Hot',
                      price:'4.99',
                      description:'A unique combination of Indian Uthappam (pancake) and Italian pizza, topped with Cerignola olives, ripe vine cherry tomatoes, Vidalia onion, Guntur chillies and Buffalo Paneer.',
                       comments: []
                };



    });

</script>
```